# Memory bloat when building records on relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, mongoid

I'm experiencing process taking too much memory when building records on a relation. It should be expected when talking about code like this:

Note that `Scan` and `Item` are Mongoid documents and scan `has_many` items.

```
1000.times do
  item = scan.items.build
  item.save
end
```

I don't need that relation to hold those objects, so my first try to bypass that was something like this:

```
1000.times do
  item = Item.new(scan_id: scan.id)
  item.save
end
```

Unfortunately it produces the same result. It's not in garbage collection. Here's a quick test:

```
class Foo
end

1000.times do |i|
  foo = Foo.new
  if i % 100 == 0
    ObjectSpace.garbage_collect 
    puts ObjectSpace.each_object(Foo).count 
  end  
end 

# => 1
# => 2
# => 2
# => 2
# => 2
# => 2
# => 2
# => 2
# => 2
# => 2

1000.times do |i|
  item = Item.new(scan_id: scan.id)
  item.save
  if i % 100 == 0
    ObjectSpace.garbage_collect 
    puts ObjectSpace.each_object(Item).count 
  end  
end 

# => 100
# => 200
# => 300
# => 400
# => 500
# => 600
# => 700
# => 800
# => 900
# => 1000
```

So my question is how to create records with a reference of a relation without bloating memory caused by `scan.items` relation holding those objects? Is it even possible?

Edit:

Even reloading `scan` with `reload` method every once in a while doesn't help, nor WeakRef.

Comment: Is it possible that you have enabled identity map for mongoid?

Comment: Heureka! Yes, I do, identity map haven't cross my mind at all and it seems to be the issue here from what I'm seeing in console now. You want to post an answer so I can mark it as accepted? Well done, rubish.

Comment: I am glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably caused by identity map. Identity map stores the documents in memory so they can be reused instead of hitting db multiple times for same document. In rails identity map is cleared automatically after each request, so generally we do not notice much difference in memory consumption. However when working outside the request-response cycle one should use `unit_of_work`. Take a look at [Mongoid: IdentityMap](http://mongoid.org/docs/identity_map.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to leverage ActiveRecords find_each if possible

[APi on ActiveRecord's Find Each](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each)

If that's not doable then I would do a find_in_batches. Good luck!

Comment: I don't understand what that has in common with my issue here. More explanation would be welcomed.

Comment: if its the memory usage you're worried about find in batches will significantly reduce the memory requirement.

Comment: Check out this article for a better explainations. Specifically #4. http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/05/05/five-common-rails-mistakes/

Comment: @engineerDave Question relates to mongoid and not active-record. #4 in the article doesn't apply here. Mongoid already uses mongodb cursor under the covers which yields documents in kind-of batches mechanism. Also op is not iterating over records but just a numbers(`1000.times`) so loading all documents is not an issue.